# Improve scala list query

Tags: scala, list, filter

I have code as below:

```
for (user <- allValidationTransaction){
    val u_t = allTrainTransaction.slice(0, allTrainTransaction.
    indexWhere(_.Transaction_ID == user.Transaction_ID)).
            filter(_.CARD_ID == user.CARD_ID)
}
```

How I improve it? It is slow.

Comment: Using a `Vector` instead of a `List` would be an improvement.

Comment: How big is the list?? Can you use parallel collections??

Comment: My list has 600,000 rows.

Comment: it does make sense to use parallel collection than. On how many cores are you running this???

Comment: Really don't have time to look for right example. https://github.com/axel22/parprog-snippets Try find something here

Comment: Also I would advise you to use scalaMeter for performance mesurement

Answer (score 0):

That will be four or more times faster depending of the cores number. Using two cores 2.5Ghz with 30000 rows is five times faster. Note that the more rows the more degradation with List.

```
 val allValidationTransaction: IndexedSeq[tranx] = IndexedSeq.fill(30000)(random)
 val allTrainTransaction : IndexedSeq[userx] = IndexedSeq.fill(30000)(random_u)

 for (user <- allValidationTransaction){
  val u_t = allTrainTransaction.par.slice(0, allTrainTransaction.par.
    indexWhere(_.Transaction_ID == user.Transaction_ID)).
        filter(_.CARD_ID == user.CARD_ID)
 }
```

Check the CPU use to observe how par collection is able to distribute the computation.

Comment: I don't know why but it is slow. :(

Comment: How much time does it takes for you. Maybe with 600k rows it´s necessary other strategy. How are the structures. Did you watch the %CPU?

Comment: Thank you for your response . I test it. `Vector` with `.par` and without `.par' is faster than `IndexedSeq` with `.par` and without `.par`.

Answer (score 0):

If your collections - allValidationTransaction and allTrainTransaction cannot be accessed randomly, your code is not efficient.
For example, slice and indexWhere of list are not constant operations.
See http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html

> Time: List has O(1) prepend and head/tail access. Most other
>   operations are O(n) on the number of elements in the list. This
>   includes the index-based lookup of elements, length, append and
>   reverse.

Moreover, if your code traverses allTrainTransaction collection 3 times per each user.

1. To find index which has same transaction id
2. To slice (if it is not random-accessible)
3. To filter which has same card id

If you change your code to procedural style, you can get performance benefit slightly.

Below is updated answer. Code is not tested. But it seems to work.

```
@tailrec
def helper[T](acc: Vector[T], trainTransactions: List[T], validTransaction: T): Vector[T] = 
  trainTransactions match {
    case trainTransaction :: otherTrainTransactions if trainTransaction.Transaction_ID == validTransaction.Transaction_ID =>
      acc

    case trainTransaction :: otherTrainTransactions if trainTransaction.CARD_ID == validTransaction.CARD_ID =>
      helper(acc :+ trainTransaction, otherTrainTransactions, validTransaction)

    case trainTransaction :: otherTrainTransactions =>
      helper(acc, otherTrainTransactions, validTransaction)

    case Nil => Nil
  }

allValidationTransaction.foldLeft(Vector.empty) {
  case (acc, validationTransaction) =>
    acc ++ helper(acc, allTrainTransactions, validationTransaction)
}
```

Comment: You're right. But functional programming is so interesting. I wanted to know how can I improve this query?